# Find _ng_content (angular) elements by name using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to match on _ng_content tags using selenium (python). I cannot match on class as there are lots of same classes with different content. The webpage appears to be divided by , ,  and so on. To complicate matters, the "**xxx**" changes with each login sesssion. ie it might be today "**xcc**" tomorrow it might be "**xcv**".

I need to get a list of all of the elem that have  All of the other attributes ie (class, label ) are repeated multiple times on the same web page. An example would be **<span _ngcontent-xxx-c324 class"ng-star inserted">**{Displayed Text}. I am trying to get a list of all of the texts listed in a table grouped by the **_ngcontent-xxx-c324**. How can I locate elements using the _ngcontent-xxx-c324 as the identifier?

Thanks for any help!

This is what I am trying to use:

```
for elem in drv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[text()="c324"]'):
    print (elem.text)
```

Comment: sometimes objects with the same classes may have different other values - `name`, `data-item`, inner text `[contains(@text, "Hello")]`. or different parents with unique values. - ie `//div[@id="Hello"]/span`

Comment: I didn't test but maybe it could work `//*[@_ngcontent-xxx-c324]`. Normally it work but I don't know if it works with `-` in name.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. the issue is how to search on the "_ngcontains*" field, I am not what this is even called since different then <span id="" or class="" etc. its just a name that I am not sure how its associated with the html function tag.

Comment: Heres what I've tried:

for elem in drv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@c324]'):
    print (elem.text)
for elem in drv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[@c324]'):
    print (elem.text)
for elem in drv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'c324'):
    print (elem.text)
for elem in drv.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//span[contains(text(),"c324")]'):
    print (elem.text)

Comment: I don't know if `xpath` has method to search item using only part of attribute's name - but Selenium can run JavaScript and maybe you could use it to search elements - using function similar to function in my answer with `BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 0):

You can get `driver.page_source` and use it with `BeautifulSoup`
which can use function in `find_all(function)`. And this function can check all attributes `.attrs` using `.startswith("_ngcontent-")` and `.endwith("-324")`

Instead of `.startswith()`, `.endswith()` you can use `regex`.

---

Miminal working example:

```
html = '''
<span _ngcontent-xxx-c324>Hello</span>
<span _ngcontent-ttt-c324>World!</span>
<span other>Other</span>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page.source, 'html.parser')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

def my_function(item):
    for key in item.attrs.keys():
        print('[DEBUG] checking:', key)
        #if key.startswith('_ngcontent-') and key.endswith('-c324'):
        if re.match('_ngcontent-.*-c324', key):
            return True
    return False
    
found = soup.find_all(my_function)    

for item in found:
    print('found:', item)
```

Result:

```
[DEBUG] checking: _ngcontent-xxx-c324
[DEBUG] checking: _ngcontent-ttt-c324
[DEBUG] checking: other

found: <span _ngcontent-xxx-c324="">Hello</span>
found: <span _ngcontent-ttt-c324="">World!</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous answer I used `BeautifulSoup` to search items but `Selenium` can `execute_script` to run `JavaScript` so you may try to do the same with `JavaScript`

I search `span` with `xpath` and later I uses `for` loop to run JavaScript on every element and check if its atrributes

```
all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span')


for item in all_items:
    result = driver.execute_script('return [... arguments[0].attributes].map(x => x.name).filter(x => (x.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & x.endsWith("c324")))', item)
    print('result:', result)
    if result:
        #print('  item:', item)
        print('  text:', item.text)
```

You may try to use `xpath` directly in `JavaScript`.

---

Full working example which I used for tests:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

#import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

#driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/home/furas/bin/chromedriver', service_args=['--quiet'])
#driver = uc.Chrome()

# --- 

html = '''
<span _ngcontent-xxx-c324>Hello</span>
<span _ngcontent-ttt-c324>World!</span>
<span other>Other</span>
'''
# ---

#driver.get(url)
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

all_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//span')
#print('len(all_items):', len(all_items))

for item in all_items:
    result = driver.execute_script('return [... arguments[0].attributes].map(x => x.name).filter(x => (x.startsWith("_ngcontent-") &      x.endsWith("c324")))', item)
    #result = driver.execute_script('return [... arguments[0].attributes].filter(x => (x.name.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & x.name.endsWith("c324")))', item)
    print('result:', result)
    if result:
        #print('  item:', item)
        print('  text:', item.text)
     
    #print(item.get_property('attributes'))  # doesn't work for me on `Firefox` (maybe works on Chrome ???)
```

---

**EDIT:**
You can search `span` and filter by attribute's name directly in `JavaScript`:

```
script = """
function filter_by_attribute_name(item) {
  for(attrib of item.attributes) {
    if(attrib.name.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & attrib.name.endsWith("c324")) {
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
items =  document.querySelectorAll("span");
return [... items].filter(filter_by_attribute_name);
"""

items = driver.execute_script(script)
```

Or with `.filter()`

```
script = """
function filter_by_attribute_name(item) {
  attribs = [... item.attributes].filter(attrib => (attrib.name.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & attrib.name.endsWith("c324")))
  return attribs.length > 0;
}

items =  document.querySelectorAll("span");
return [... items].filter(filter_by_attribute_name);
"""

items = driver.execute_script(script)
```

---

Full working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

#import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

#driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/home/furas/bin/chromedriver', service_args=['--quiet'])
#driver = uc.Chrome()

# --- 

html = '''
<span _ngcontent-xxx-c324>Hello</span>
<span _ngcontent-ttt-c324>World!</span>
<span other>Other</span>
<span>No Attributes</span>
'''
# ---

#driver.get(url)
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html)

print('--- script 1 ---')

script = """
function filter_by_attribute_name(item) {
  for(attrib of item.attributes) {
    if(attrib.name.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & attrib.name.endsWith("c324")) {
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
items =  document.querySelectorAll("span");
return [... items].filter(filter_by_attribute_name);
"""

items = driver.execute_script(script)
for item in items:
    print('item:', item.tag_name, item.text)

# ---

print('--- script 2 ---')

script = """
function filter_by_attribute_name(item) {
  attribs = [... item.attributes].filter(attrib => (attrib.name.startsWith("_ngcontent-") & attrib.name.endsWith("c324")))
  return attribs.length > 0;
}

items =  document.querySelectorAll("span");
return [... items].filter(filter_by_attribute_name);
"""

items = driver.execute_script(script)
for item in items:
    print('item:', item.tag_name, item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone! I figured out the issue: Selenium via Python does not handle attributes with dashes\hyphens in them You have to use '\\tag[contains(@name-with-dashes,"textstring")]' to find them. I had no clue that a field name containing dashes or hyphens isn't supported (at least with python)!